# "Normalizing" BigDecimal's hash code: howto?

Tags: java, guava, hashcode, bigdecimal

I have a JSON Schema implementation written in Java which depends on [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) (version 2.1.x). For accuracy reasons, I tell Jackson to use `BigDecimal` for floating point numbers.

For the needs of JSON Schema, there is a particular need: JSON value equality, for numeric values, is defined by the equality of their mathematical value. I need this kind of check since, for instance, this is not a legal schema (values in an `enum` should be unique):

```
{ "enum": [ 1, 1.0 ] }
```

But JsonNodes for `1` and `1.0` are not equal. Therefore, I have coded an implementation of Guava's [Equivalence](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html), and use `Set<Equivalence.Wrapper<JsonNode>>` where appropriate. And this implementation should work for all types of nodes, not just numeric nodes.

And the most difficult part of this implementation turns out to be `doHash()` for numeric nodes :/ I need *the same hashcode for equivalent mathematical values*, whether they are integers or floating point numbers.

The best I could come up with at the moment is this:

```
@Override
protected int doHash(final JsonNode t)
{
    /*
     * If this is a numeric node, we want a unique hashcode for all possible
     * number nodes.
     */
    if (t.isNumber()) {
        final BigDecimal decimal = t.decimalValue();
        try {
            return decimal.toBigIntegerExact().hashCode();
        } catch (ArithmeticException ignored) {
            return decimal.stripTrailingZeros().hashCode();
        }
    }

    // etc etc -- the rest works fine
```

This is, at the moment, the best I could come up with.

Is there a better way for calculating such a hashcode?

(*edit: full code of the Equivalence implementation [here](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eel/kitchen/jsonschema/util/jackson/JsonNodeEquivalence.java)*)

Comment: @zsxwing: doEquivalent is already overriden -- see edit, I have added a link to the full implementation

Comment: Not clear -- is there a problem that the code is not returning equal hash codes for equal values, or are you (mistakenly) trying to assure a unique hash code for every distinct value?

Comment: Do you want that "1", "1.0", "1.00" return the same hash code? Maybe you can use TreeSet which does not use the hashCode?

Comment: Remember the critical rule for hash codes:  If two objects compare as equal, they ***must*** have identical hash codes.

Comment: @HotLicks I know that... The problem is that I need the same hash code for two _mathematically equivalent_ BigDecimals, and of course I cannot rely on `.equals()` -- I thought the question made that clear

Comment: @zsxwing that is exactly what I want, and at a given point in time I will only ever have one of these three -- so TreeSet is not an option

Comment: Offhand, it looks like what you have should work, though perhaps a little clumsy.  Never really played with BigDecimal, though, to know what might work better.  (Might be able to do something with unscaledValue, but I haven't quite figured out what that's doing.)

Comment: Edited the question so that it is less verbose

Comment: If you touch anything in floating-point, all bets are off as float/double are _inexact_ representations of _most_ numbers. A trivial example is the number `1.2`. The closest double representation is actually `1.1999999999999999555910790...`. You think you can just round, but it gets worse: `1.55` is actually `1.5500000000000000444089...` which rounds to one decimal place as `1.6`, but `2.55` is `2.5499999999999998223...` which rounds the other way.

Comment: @JimGarrison this is precisely why I ask Jackson to always use BigDecimal for floating points

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Convert to Double and use the Double's hashCode, but base equality on the BigDecimal compareTo order.

Two numerically equivalent BigDecimals will map to the same Double, and get the same hashCode. Some BigDecimal values that are very slightly different will get the same hashcode because of double rounding, but most distinct values will get different hashcodes, which is all you need.

Comment: I use `.compareTo()` for equality indeed. That is so simple a solution that I didn't think about it...

Comment: I am curious, though, as to what double values are returned for very large values, which `double` cannot handle because of a lack of precision?

Comment: All numbers greater than Double.MAX_VALUE will be mapped to infinity, and get the same hashcode. Similarly, very small numbers will map to zero, and get the same hashcode. Otherwise, pairs of distinct numbers that match in about the 16 most significant digits will get the same hashcode.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'd have never though about this.

Comment: Good idea!  A little orthogonal thinking is often productive.

Comment: Scala has a wrapper around java BigDecimal that provides a better hashCode (and equals) that you might be interested in. Have a look at computeHashCode here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/math/BigDecimal.scala

Answer (score 11):

Use `BigDecimal::stripTrailingZeros()` method, it returns the same `BigDecimal` object for two different `BigDecimal` objects which represent the same mathematical number, i.e., they have different number of non-meaningful digits, for example `3.50` (scale is two) and `3.5` (scale is one):

```
return decimal.stripTrailingZeros().hashCode();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for reasons pointed out by @patricia-shanahan

Comment: @KnightIndustries you are confused, what's important is the following, which is what I was talking about: `(new BigDecimal("1E+2")).stripTrailingZeros().hashCode()` returns the same integer value as `(new BigDecimal("100")).stripTrailingZeros().hashCode()`, you may run the code yourself.

Comment: True. When applied to both sides, `stripTrailingZeros()` seems to actually "normalize" also mixed exponential notations like `100` and `1E+2`. I deleted my previous comment.